# Generating a step-by-step reduction of a Haskell expression

Tags: haskell

Is there a system that will generate a step-by-step reduction of a Haskell expression? The intent is to provide a tutorial example of lazy evaluation. It would be nice if it were written in Haskell, but that isn't a requirement.

For example, assume we have:

```
myCycle xs = xs `myAppend` myCycle xs

[] `myAppend` ys = ys
(x:xs) `myAppend` ys = x: (xs `myAppend` ys)

myTake 0 _  = []
myTake _ [] = []
myTake n (x:xs) = x: (myTake (n-1) xs)
```

The evaluation of `> myTake 3 $ myCycle [1, 2]` should show a sequence like this. (Please correct me if I made any mistakes in this.)

```
>  myTake 3 $ myCycle [1, 2]
=> myTake 3 ([1, 2] `myAppend` myCycle [1, 2])
=> myTake 3 (1:([2] `myAppend` myCycle [1, 2]))
=> 1: myTake 2 ([2] `myAppend` myCycle [1, 2]) -- Not showing 3-1 => 2
=> 1: myTake 2 (2:([] `myAppend` myCycle [1, 2]))
=> 1:2: myTake 1 ([] `myAppend` myCycle [1, 2])
=> 1:2: myTake 1 (myCycle [1, 2])
=> 1:2: myTake 1 ([1, 2] `myAppend` myCycle [1, 2])
=> 1:2: myTake 1 (1:([2] `myAppend` myCycle [1, 2]))
=> 1:2:1: myTake 0 ([2] `myAppend` myCycle [1, 2])
=> 1:2:1:[] = [1, 2, 1]
```

The point of all this is to illustrate how lazy evaluation makes infinite lists possible.

Comment: https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2017/09/visualize-cbn/

Comment: http://chrisuehlinger.com/LambdaBubblePop/

Comment: Thanks. Those are both very nice.

Comment: Any reason why those are comments rather than answers?

Comment: This is a wonderful tool! can it support complex expression like this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123307/how-to-print-intermediate-result-in-functor-and-applicative-in-haskell