# how to print intermediate result in Functor and Applicative in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am reading the book Programming in Haskell 2nd by Graham Hutton.
https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pih.html#slides

When it comes to  chapter 13.4 Sequencing parsers, it contains the following functions:

```
> parse three "abcdef" 
[((’a’,’c’),"def")] 
> parse three "ab" 
[]
```

I would like to understand what are the intermediate steps to evaluate them behind the scene. You can find the working source code for the Functor and Applicative for the Parser here:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char

-- Basic definitions
newtype Parser a =
  P (String -> [(a, String)])
parse (P p) inp = p inp


item :: Parser Char
item = P (\inp -> case inp of
         [] -> []
         (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)])

-- Sequencing parsers
instance Functor Parser
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
                                               where
  fmap g p =
    P
      (\inp ->
         case parse p inp of
           [] -> []
           [(v, out)] -> [(g v, out)])
--parse  (fmap toUpper item) "abc"

instance Applicative Parser
   -- pure :: a -> Parser a
                            where
  pure v = P (\inp -> [(v, inp)])
   -- <*> :: Parser (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
  pg <*> px =
    P
      (\inp ->
         case parse pg inp of
           [] -> []
           [(g, out)] -> parse (fmap g px) out)

three :: Parser (Char, Char)
three = pure g <*> item <*> item <*> item
  where
    g x y z = (x, z)
```

I have attempted it by substituting the definitions from Functor and Applicative in the following way, but dont know how to do it further:

```
parse three "abc"



three :: Parser (Char,Char) 
three 
= pure g <*> item <*> item <*> item 
=P (\inp -> [(g,inp)]) <*> item <*> item <*> item        (apply pure v)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=P (
\inp -> case parse P (\inp -> [(g,inp)]) inp of         (apply pg <*> px)
[] -> [] 
[(g,out)] -> parse (fmap g item) out
)

<*> item <*> item 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=P (
\inp -> case (\inp -> [(g,inp)]) inp of             (apply parse (P p) inp = p inp
[] -> [] 
[(g,out)] -> parse (fmap g item) out
)

<*> item <*> item 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here, inp=”abc”,  (\inp -> [(g,inp)]),  inp = [  (f x y z =(x,z), “abc”   )]  
=P (
parse (
fmap g item
) out
)                               (apply \inp -> [(g,inp)] on inp)

<*> item <*> item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is in response to the 'Based on the suggestion of @Daniel Wagner, I expand on `fmap g p`:' update)

> Is the last substitution correct?

It's impossible to answer because steps before that are incorrect.

There are several problems with your expansion, indicating that you're being sloppy when writing, which has led to mistakes. There might also be conceptual problems.

For example, when you inline `three = P ...` into `parse three "abc"`, you didn't put parentheses around `P ...`, leading to this line:

> ```
> parse P (parse (P ...)) <*> item <*> item "abc"
> ```

This is most likely syntactically incorrect, as it would be parsed like

```
(parse P (parse (P ...))) <*> item <*> (item "abc")
```

While you likely meant:

```
parse ((P ...) <*> item <*> item) "abc"
```

If you think, well I'm just doing this to make things easier to write, then check this out: This syntax error also led you to erroneously work on the `parse P (parse (P ...))` part independently of `<*> item <*> item "abc"`, which a serious mistake and made most of everything following that irrelevant.

Another thing is this:

> ```
> Here, inp="abc",  (\inp -> [(g,inp)]),  inp = [  (f x y z =(x,z), "abc"   )]
> ```

This line makes no sense at all. Since you are just expanding `three`, It's not valid to say that `inp` is anything. Consider `(\x -> x)`. The `x` here is merely to establish the relationship that the result is the same as the argument, and is not any particular value. This is what is meant by it being a *bound* variable.

(And I don't even know what you're talking about when you say `(\inp -> [(g,inp)]),  inp = [  (f x y z =(x,z), "abc"   )]`. Maybe you can clarify?)

This also means that the following makes no sense

> ```
>  (\inp -> case parse item inp of [] -> []; [(v, out)] -> [(g v, out)]))<*> item <*> item “abc”
> ={substitute inp for "abc"}
>  case parse item  "abc" of [] -> []; [(v, out)] -> [(g v, out)]<*> item <*> item
> ```

There are multiple problems here. To begin with, the first line has an extra close paren, which makes it hard to see what you mean. If we ignore that, then before you had `(\inp ->) <*> item ...`, but afterwards you did not put parens around the `case` expression, making `<*>`.

Also, it seems that you want to do a beta-reduction here. A beta reduction always has the form `(\v -> E) a`, in which the lambda is directly applied to an argument. You cannot just say randomly that '`v` is equal to `a`' and jump around in expressions.

For example, If we have `f (\x -> x + 1) 3`, is it right to reduce that to `f 4`? No, because the lambda isn't being applied to `3`.

This means that even if the first half is right, the second half of what you wrote is based on a nonsensical step and is irrelevant.

---

I would very much want to tell you how to fix your reduction, but I'm sorry to say that I think what you wrote is beyond repair by now. If you want to have a correct reduction trace, please be more careful with both the syntax and the validity of each step, and do everything again from scratch.

As an aid, there are several things you should check to see if things went wrong:

1. Each step should be syntactically valid. No unbound variables, no missing parens, etc.
2. If the original expression typechecks, then each step must also typecheck and have the same type.

Comment: looks like each expansion can be verified by ghci, as long as there is a way to type multi-line function:

`parse (P (parse (fmap g item)) <*> item <*> item) "abc"` works, But how can we expand fmap in a way we can type into ghci? The following has indentation problem in ghci:
`parse (P (parse (P (\inp -> case parse item inp of [] -> []; [(v, out)] -> [(g v, out)])) <*> item <*> item) "abc"`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're going for, but the code you mentioned doesn't parse because there's a parenthesis mismatch.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dramforever/0d5daf337bf516babe5d1c9a63c11ee9

Your answer here is perfect for my question. I am thinking about whether we can turn it to be a generalized tool for reduction for  any function evaluation with Functor and Applicative

Answer (score 1):

It's a good start. Your last step doesn't look quite right. Stripping off the shared parts, you've written that

```
\inp -> case (\inp -> [(g,inp)]) inp of [] -> []; [(g, out)] -> parse (fmap g item) out
=
                                                                parse (fmap g item) out
```

This equation doesn't look quite right to me: the former is a function, and the latter isn't. Additionally, the latter refers to the free variable `out`, while the former doesn't (because `out` is bound by the pattern match it's enclosed in). A more careful continuation looks like this:

```
\inp -> case (\inp -> [(g,inp)]) inp of [] -> []; [(g, out)] -> parse (fmap g item) out
= { beta reduction, substituting inp for inp }
\inp -> case [(g, inp)]              of [] -> []; [(g, out)] -> parse (fmap g item) out
= { case reduction, substituting g for g and inp for out }
\inp ->                                                         parse (fmap g item) inp
```

If you like, you could then eta-reduce this to `parse (fmap g item)`. Plugging this back into the shared parts we dropped above, we have:

```
three
=
P (parse (fmap g item)) <*> item <*> item
```

The result can be verified in ghci:

```
*Parsing> parse three "abc"
[(('a','c'),"")]

*Parsing> let g x y z = (x,z)

*Parsing> parse (P (parse (fmap g item)) <*> item <*> item) "abc"
[(('a','c'),"")]
```

As next steps, there are three places you could do your next definition-expansion to enable further progress:

1. You could expand the `fmap` in `fmap g item`.
2. You could expand the inner `(<*>)` in `P (...) <*> item`.
3. You could expand the outer `(<*>)` in `(P (...) <*> item) <*> item`.

Good luck!

Comment: is there any tool to automate this expansion while showing all the intermediate steps?
Or is it the way how ghci/ghc evaluate expression?

Comment: `You could expand the outer (<*>) in (P (...) <*> item) <*> item`
Should I fully expand the function first before I apply it on `inp="abc"`?

Comment: I do not know of a tool that automates the expansion. Whether you first fully expand `three` or not before finding redexes in its context of `parse three "abc"` provably does not matter: any reduction order which terminates will produce the same answer.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chakpongchung/5aba77535b318ce168e46342c8212462

This is the answer I was looking for, which answered my question perfectly. 

I wonder whether it is possible to implement a tool to generate steps like this(valid haskell code that can be parsed by GHC ) for any function evaluation using reduction.